# Imported Old site to new url, pages looping on a redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming

I moved my old site to my new url http://www.polestardistribution.com with no problem. Imported the old files, imported the old database, everything was super smooth until I checked the sites pages and posts.

For some reason I have to use the default permalink settings, no other settings will work and throw me into a redirect loop to no where.

Any suggestions would be great, I'm willing to try anything.

I'm using Yahoo! hosting,not by my choice, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing any instances of your old domain name in your database and .htaccess file with the new domain name.

Comment: Did it to the database. Let me check the htaccess again to make sure. Tried to upload my old.htaccess file and got blocked by yahoo, that;s probably what it is. Will keep you informed.

Comment: Yes, Yahoo! doesn't allow .htaccess file uploads for some reason. Guess I'll be using ugly urls for this site.

Comment: Quick note. added /index.php/%postname%/ in the permalinks field, works now. Longer urls, but not as ugly.